# Can we use JAVA based drools rules in .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, jboss, drools

I have a JAVA application which using drools rules.I need create a similar application in .NET.
Can i use same drools rule file in  .NET application?.
If it need to be converted ,Is there any automated way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Drools is a Java application, and there is no port that would enable you to re-use DRL in a .NET application.

If you want to re-use your knowledge base, then you should expose it as a web service and call that from your .NET application.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search found this - http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/, the key bit here seems to be:

> Drools.NET is a Business Rules Engine (BRE) based on Charles Forgy's Rete algorithm.     Developers can now exploit a powerful Rule Engine through a completely managed .NET code base! Drools.NET is based on Jboss Rules, and comes with all the features of that Rules Engine.

So I would guess this might be what you are after from the point of view of using any existing rules and definitions - I'm assuming you'll be rewriting the code itself regardless.

Comment: I guess you posted answer in [wrong thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23513101/2530848) :-D

Comment: Steer well clear of Drools.NET - it hasn't been updated for years and the syntax has changed a lot since then. It won't let you re-use any of the DRL from your Java project.

Comment: @Steve- Can i use WWF instead of Drool.NET?Is there any limitation for WWF?